# How do I write in the 2nd column and enter marks in the third column

Tags: tables, exam

[image]I have created a table for a Marking Scheme of an exam paper. My question is how to wrap text in the 2nd column only and enter marks corresponding to that step in the 3rd column. I have read some documentation and I do not know how to do this. Here is my code below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\begin{document}
{
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
    \newcommand{\rr}{\raggedright}
    \newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline}
    \begin{tabular}{|@{}c|l|l|}
        \hline
        %\rowcolor{gray!20}
        \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textbf {Q.no}}&
        \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textbf{Scheme}}&
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Mark}}\\\hline \hline
        \rule{0pt}{25pt}1 &  $\displaystyle{\frac{3x^2-x-2}{x^2-1}=\frac{3x^2-3x+2x-2}{(x-1)(x+1)}}$ [Splitting middle term]  & B1 \\ \hline
        2 &  Row 2 & \\ \hline
        3 & Row 3 & \\ \hline
        4 & & \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear what exactly you want to achieve. Can you maybe put a picture showing the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You loaded `tabulary`, but in case you want to stretch your table to the full page with, `tabularx` may be a better choice. It provides the column specifier `X` that stretches the column so that the table will take the full with.

Then, you want to have line breaks in your cells. This can simply be achieved with using `\newline`. But since you put some formulas inside the cell, better wrap it in a `\makecell` macro. This way, you finally can use the `cellspace` package to add some spacing above and below the contents of the cells. If you do not wrap the formulas inside the `\makecell` macro, the `cellspace` macros may not have the desired effect.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{5pt}

\begin{document}
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
 \newcommand{\rr}{\raggedright}

 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|S{X}|l|}
  \hline
  \textbf{Q.no} &
  \textbf{Scheme} &
  \textbf{Mark} \\ \hline \hline
  1 & \makecell[lt]{$\displaystyle{\frac{3x^2-x-2}{x^2-1}}$ \\ 
      $\displaystyle{=\frac{3x^2-3x+2x-2}{(x-1)(x+1)}}$} & B1 \\ \hline
  2 & Row 2 & \\ \hline
  3 & Row 3 & \\ \hline
  4 &  & \\ \hline
 \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]